# get value from asp boundfield and store to sql database via button click?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, boundfield

i want to get this value from webform 1 (admin side) when button is clicked:

here is my full viewcreditrequest code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>

           <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
            SortExpression="Username" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="EmailAddress" 
            SortExpression="EmailAddress" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyAddress" HeaderText="CompanyAddress" 
            SortExpression="CompanyAddress" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="IncomeRange" HeaderText="IncomeRange" 
            SortExpression="IncomeRange" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreditRequest" HeaderText="CreditRequest" 
            SortExpression="CreditRequest" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="ContactNumber" SortExpression="ContactNumber" />

        <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CreditRequest") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["IslandGasAdminFM"] != null)
        {

            bindgrid();
            Label1.Text = "- Finance Manager";

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Finance Manager credentials needed'); window.location.href='LogIn.aspx';</script>");
        }
    }
    public void bindgrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CreditRequests ", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from CreditRequests", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "data");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and pass it on to webform 2 (client side):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCredit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

this is what i got so far:

admin side:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" OnClick ="btnApprove_Click" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind:

```
protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code for getting the boundfield "creditrequest" and if possible, store it in database for future use.
    }
```

is there any way to get the creditrequest value from boundfield and store it in database?

Comment: you can use query string

Comment: can you site an example pls sir regarding my case @VijayGautam

Comment: is that button is in gridview.?

Comment: not in gridview sir

Comment: but you are using gridview , right? since you are using `asp:BoundField`

Comment: yes correct @VijayGautam

Comment: can you please help me out @VijayGautam, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499531/gridview-row-command-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do two thing's `1.since` you are using Button, add a new row in gridview like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CreditRequest") %>' runat="server" Text="View" ID="btnEdit" OnClick="btnEdit_OnClick"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

and the code behind is like this

```
 protected void btnEdit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                string id = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument.ToString();
                Response.Redirect("yourpagename.aspx?value=" + id);
            }
        }
```

and on another page Client side get the query string value like this

```
string value = Request.QueryString["value"])
```

And **2nd** and easy method will be to use hyperlink instead of button  like this

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CreditRequest", "~/yourpagename.aspx?value={0}") %>' Text="Edit" "></asp:HyperLink>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: can it be just a label confirmation and not a response.redirect?

Comment: did you get the value in query string .? if yes the just set the textbox value to query string value

Comment: but you want to move from one page to another page , right?

Comment: since the admin is sending the approval, its not necessary to redirect to another page sir. just the creditrequest value (to the client textbox)

Comment: change `string value = Request.QueryString["value"];` to `txtCredit.Text = Request.QueryString["value"];`

Comment: making sense. but on the button click, its not even redirecting to another page?

Comment: 2nd method is working. it passes the value to the textbox. is there a way to avoid the redirection page? and just have a confirmation label?

Comment: also, can i save the transferred value to the logged in customer?

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod maybe i am not fully understanding what you want to do, however if you want to avoid redirection then save the value in database and when client page loads check the confirmation value from database and then show to client ,

Comment: and you can save the values , but for this you have to use button and save values on button click event

Comment: i have changed it to button sir. im trying out your solution to save the value and database. however, any functions in my button is not being read? i have this inside my template field: <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" OnClick ="btnApprove_Click" />

Comment: maybe because of some validations the button is not being submitted use this `<asp:Button ID="btnApprove" formnovalidate runat="server" Text="Approve" OnClick ="btnApprove_Click" />` , `formnovalidate ` avoid any validation issue.

Comment: still not firing sir :(

Comment: its now working. should i start with the insert command? for me to be able to get credit request value from boundfield?

Comment: sir, i have managed to make it work. but its not showing anything? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499531/gridview-row-command-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code below EXACTLY as I'm showing and it will work. I've just tested on my computer:

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CreditRequest" HeaderText="Credit Request" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CreditRequest") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class delete_me : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)//THIS IS IMPORTANT.GridView1_RowCommand will not fire unless you add this line
        {
            var p1 = new Person() { Name = "Person 1",CreditRequest="Credit Request 1" };
            var p2 = new Person() { Name = "Person 2",CreditRequest="Credit Request 2" };

            var list = new List<Person> { p1, p2 };
            GridView1.DataSource = list;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        if(e.CommandName == "Approve")
        {
            string creditRequest = e.CommandArgument as string;
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreditRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please see updated sir. i have included my full code. what i want is to get a specific boundfield value and maybe store it to database for future use to another webpage. thanks sir

Comment: Well that's what my example is showing you.I have a bound field called CreditRequest and when a user clicks on the Approve button you can access it's value in the GridView1_RowCommand event

Comment: A field or property with the name 'Username' was not found on the selected data source. error sir

Comment: Where do you get this error?When you click on btnApprove?

Comment: when i run the webform sir.

Comment: Hold on.Did your grid view ever display any data?This sounds like you have an error in the bindgrid() method or you do not have a column called Username in the CreditRequests table.Debug that method properly and make sure ds.Tables[0].DefaultView actually has data

Comment: bindgrid is working fine sir. it displays data. but when i pasted your code, it gives me that error. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113213/discussion-between-denis-wessels-and-paolo-duhaylungsod).

Comment: managed to make it work but its not showing any result sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499531/gridview-row-command-not-working