# asp button on click inside item template not firing

Tags: asp.net, button, onclick, itemtemplate

Not able to make this work.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" OnClick ="btnApprove_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind:

```
protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("viewprofile.aspx");
}
```

not even firing when button is clicked. any tricks on this?

Comment: just put one lable and change text of label when button click event and see label text is change or not.....

Comment: not firing even the response redirect sir @PHPDeveloper

Comment: are you using any update panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `EnableEventValidation="false"` right at the top in your Page directive:

`<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" Language="C#"`...

Just beware that setting this value to false can expose your website to security vulnerabilities.As an alternative, instead of setting `EnableEventValidation="false"` you can handle the grid views `OnRowCommand`:

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="Approve" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class delete_me : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)//THIS IS IMPORTANT.GridView1_RowCommand will not fire unless you add this line
        {
            var p1 = new Person() { Name = "Person 1" };
            var p2 = new Person() { Name = "Person 2" };

            var list = new List<Person> { p1, p2 };
            GridView1.DataSource = list;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks sir Denis

Comment: can you help me out with my other concern sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497123/get-value-from-asp-boundfield-and-store-to-sql-database-via-button-click

Answer (score -1):

You Just put on your gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Also put code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
        }
```

Try!!!! it's working fine...

Comment: whats the difference sir?